# Array of objects is empty after an object is added on "click"

Tags: javascript, oop, asynchronous, dom

How can I access an array of objects after user submits their name in a form?

I have a simple text field and submit button. I'd like for the user to submit their name and have that name stored in an array of objects that I can access globally. When I `console.log` the array after the user submits their name, I get an empty array. Is there a way to access the array with the objects stored from within?

Here's my code:

```js
let submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit_btn');
let form = document.getElementById('form')
let nameField = document.getElementById('userName');
let userList = [];

const addUser = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let user = {
    name: nameField.value
  }
  form.reset();
  userList.push(user);
  console.log('Inside addUser: ', userList);
  //localStorage.setItem('userList', JSON.stringify(userList));
}

document.getElementById('submit_btn').addEventListener('click', addUser);
console.log('Outside addUser: ', userList);
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="userName" placeholder="enter your name">
  <button type="submit" id="submit_btn">submit</button>
</form>
```

Thank you for your guidance

Comment: `console.log` inside the `addUser` function is working fine.

Comment: You _can_ access the array outside, as its declared globally. You just try to access it before any have been added in your example. Obviously its empty at that point.

Comment: thank you all- so weird, my codepen was buggin' out